# How can I parallel run same jobs on more than one slave in Jenkins, where I get the slave names and number from an XML file. Currently

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Please see the below code for reference, here the two branch in parallel is hardcoded. What if I have 3 slaves and I wanna use three branch? I want to add this third branch dynamically.

```
File file1 = new File("C:\\COPIER\\Completed\\Slave.txt");
def slave = file1.readLines()
echo slave[0]
echo slave[1]
parallel (
            firstBranch: 
            {
               build job: "Instance_Pipeline_TIACopy", parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'NODE', value: slave[1]], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'TIABuildLocation', value: "C:\\TestParallelExecution\\FirstBranch"], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'TIASlaveLocation', value: "E:\\TestParallelExecution\\FirstBranch"] ], propagate: false
               echo "First Branch Build Completed"
            }, 
            secondBranch: 
            {
               build job: "Instance_Pipeline_TIACopy", parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'NODE', value: slave[1]], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'TIABuildLocation', value: "C:\\TestParallelExecution\\SecondBranch"], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'TIASlaveLocation', value: "E:\\TestParallelExecution\\SecondBranch"] ], propagate: false
               echo "Second Branch Build Completed"
            },
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create the structure needed for the parallel step:

```
File agentsFile = new File("C:\\COPIER\\Completed\\Slave.txt");
def agents = file1.readLines()

def parallelBranches = [:]
for (int i = 0; i < agents.size(); i++) {
  parallelBranches["branches${i}"] = {
    build job: "Instance_Pipeline_TIACopy", parameters: [ [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'NODE', value: agents[i]], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'TIABuildLocation', value: "C:\\TestParallelExecution\\FirstBranch"], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'TIASlaveLocation', value: "E:\\TestParallelExecution\\${i}"] ], propagate: false
    echo "Branch #${i} Build Completed"
  }
}

parallel parallelBranches
```

Note the proper name is agent (and not slave), as per the [Jenkins glossary](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/)